# I keep getting errors in my code, specifically "Type 'FirstViewController' has no member" and "Use of unresolved identifier"

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I get errors saying, "Type 'FirstViewController' has no member 'keepTimer'" and "Use of unresolved identifier 'keepTimer'".

What am I doing wrong? How should I change this? 
My main goal is to have a stopwatch start keeping track of time. When I press Save, it should add the stopwatch value as an event in Calendar.

I have made sure all are identical. They are identical in terms of spelling, but some have () at the end. When I add () at the end, I still get errors.

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
          captureStartDateTime()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.self.keepTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        keepTimer()
        startOutlet.isHidden = true
    } ...

func keepTimer() {...}
```

Comment: There are countless examples of using Timer in Swift 4 and later. If you search for those examples you will see the proper way to pass the selector name to `#selector` and the requirements for the actual `keepTimer` function declaration.

Comment: Nowadays (2019) you are encouraged to use the [closure based API of `Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/2091889-scheduledtimer)

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: Any) {
    captureStartDateTime()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(keepTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startOutlet.isHidden = true
}

@objc func keepTimer() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, to use a method in a `#selector()`, the method must be marked with `@objc`

In your case you should be getting an error saying, `Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'keepTimer()' that is not exposed to Objective-C`
All you have to do is add `@objc` to expose this instance method to Objective-C.

i.e. your code should look like `@objc func keepTimer() {...}`

Answer (score -1):

Is the keepTimer() in the FirstViewController? If not, the Xcode may cannot recognise the function